# Modal Close Event via User Trigger

Tags: bootstrap-modal

How do I check if the bootstrap close/hide via user trigger or hidden programmatically?

```
$(modalSelector).modal('hide');
```

Does bootstrap has an event to detect if the modal closed via user trigger or programmatically? Because I want to have two different action for both event.

Thank you~

Answer (score 0):

In order to manually show the modal pop up you have to do this

`$('#myModal').modal('show');`

You previously need to initialize it with show: false so it won't show until you manually do it.

`$('#myModal').modal({ show: false})`
or
`$('#myModal').modal('hide')`

Where myModal is the name of the modal container.

Comment: Does bootstrap has an event to detect if the modal closed via user trigger or programmatically? Because I want to have two different action for both event.

Comment: Yes, flag Does . bye for now leaving from office